# Variance of delta function and Gaussian function and their co-variance

Tags: covariance, dirac-delta, variance, gaussian-integral

For x and y to be statistically independent,
I have a probability density function of delta function given as:
f(x)= 1/2(x+1) + 1/2(x-1), where x is a random variable.
From the function, I can deduce that its expected value is '0' since it is symmetric at '0'. Now I would like to find variance for this function.

Secondly, if there is another function g(y) which is a Gaussian function with mean '0'. I would like to find the variance of "z" with z=x.y and the co-variance K(YZ).

As per my working, I am confused for variance of f(x), variance can be defined as E[x^2]-E[x]^2. From this, from here I can see that E(x)^2 is zero but for E(x^2), will this be also '0'?

I found that variance of 'z' will be '0' since it is defined as E(x-E(x))(y-E(y)). Now since x and y are statistically independent, I can write it as E(xy)-E(X)E(y)=0

For co-variance of [y.z], I solved until {E[y^2.x]-E[y^2]E[x] }, not if x and y are statistically independent, will x and y^2 also be statistically independent?

I hope my working above is correct, looking for your opinions.

Comment: It is a lot easier to handle if you look at the first variable as a two state discrete random variable $X$ with $P(X=-1)=P(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$.  $E(X^2)=1$, since $X^2=1$.  For covariance, you need $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)=0$  At the end you introduce a new variable $w$ without defining it.

Comment: @herb steinberg Thanks for pointing that out, type from me. I have replaced w with z since I am interested in finding co-variance(y.z). I understood for variance of f(x) will be 1, Thanks

Comment: For your final question: $E(Y^2X)=E(Y^2)E(X)=0$.  Any function of $Y$ alone is independent of any function of $X$ alone.